# How to let my application to be running even when Logged off the machine?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have developed a TCP Server. I want my TCP server to be running even when I log off my machine. So clients can connect to it even when my computer is logged off.  I was thinking if I must create a Windows Service to implement this approach, but I am not sure how to do so.

Please tell me how can I let my application to keep working even when my machine is logged off.

Comment: Here is a good place to start. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am checking the link that you given me.

Comment: The only way to do what you want is to write a service or run your application as a service--as @JohnAtwood referenced.

Comment: Can you please give me a link to learn how to write a service in C# ?

Comment: First task in @JohnAtwood link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a service by following these instructions:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192

And then installing it to your PC should be as simple as using

```
installutil MyService.msc
```

(installutil will be part of your .NET installation, eg in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5)

You can the configure it to Startup Automatically by running `services.msc` from the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You could launch it as a task from Windows Task Scheduler and set it to run even if you aren't logged in. This would work even if the application isn't a service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  and it's a good answer but i need a more real time solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to shut down your machine and still let the client connect then you need to deploy your application on a server.

Comment: My application already running on a dedicated server, But the problem is when I log off the my server machine my application get closed. I need it to be running when logged off , i have no need it to be running when the machine is shut downed, I think you understand what I am talking about

Answer (score 0):

Create a windows service and run it as LocalService http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.80).aspx